# \ref command not working in the argument of redefined section/subsection command (UAI template)

Tags: hyperref, titlesec, templates, ref

So I used this template from this UAI conference https://auai.org/uai2021/submission_instructions.php
I found that the `\section{\ref{some_label}}` or `\subsection{\ref{some_label}}` are only compiled to be `??`.
The `\section` and `\subsection` commands are redefined in the template class file.
So I guess it has to do with the `titlesec` package or `titleformat` command. There seems also a deeper conflict between `\MakeUppercase` command and `hyperref` package.
Can anyone help take a look at the template?

Comment: Have you tried to compile the file several times?

Comment: It's probably a bug somewhere in the class file. You may want to write to the conference organizers, describe the issue to them, and ask them to fix it. Under no circumstance should you modify the class file yourself, as doing so pretty much guarantees that your paper will be rejected out of hand.

Comment: @Jes Yes, I tried compiling multiple times. Now the problem narrows down to the conflicts between the `\MakeUppercase` command and the `hyperref` package.

Comment: @Mico Yes, it is indeed a bug. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: The issue is described in http://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-casechange. The conference organizers may be able to fix it simply by loading `\RequirePackage[overload]{textcase}` in their class file.

Comment: Hi @equaeghe, thanks for your input! I read the texfaq page but it doesn't handle the issue where \ref{} is compiled to ??. The textcase seems only handles improper uppercase/lowercase transform, which is not the same issue I am having here.
I also loaded the command you suggested, but the same problem remains, e.g., \section{\ref{<some label>}} is only compiled to ??, and doesn't link to anywhere. I guess there is also a part of hyperref in this bug.

Answer (score 1):

The class has broken `\section` somehow. You should report it to the maintainers.

However a simple workaround seems to be to move `label`

```
\documentclass{uai2021}

\begin{document}

\section{zzz}\label{abc}
aaa see Section~\ref{abc}
\end{document}
```

with `\label` after the argument produces

[image]

with it in the argument

```
\documentclass{uai2021}

\begin{document}

\section{zzz\label{abc}}
aaa see Section~\ref{abc}
\end{document}
```

Gives the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\label #1->\@bsphack \begingroup \def \label@name 
                                                  {#1}\label@hook \protected...
l.5 \section{zzz\label{abc}}
                            
?
```

---

The issue can be simplified down to files just in standard distributions

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\MakeUppercase}

\begin{document}

\section{zzz\label{abc}}
aaa see Section~\ref{abc}
\end{document}
```

gives the error

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.8 \section{zzz\label{abc}}
                            
?
```

Comment: Thanks! I found out that the issue is caused by the conflict between `\MakeUppercase` command and the `hyperref` package. I manually replaced all the `\ref{}` with text to avoid the error for now.